# Discovering URI of intents

Tags: android

I have been reading quite a bit about intents and the like, and have been trying to avoid having to actually post a question. I believe what happens is you set the URI and that passes data to an intent (please correct me if I'm wrong), I am interested in using the calculator app on the phone, but I don't know HOW to determine what URI's are available of a given package (assuming URI is the correct terminology). (I'd be happy with only android native apps or any "open" apps).

Comment: You can use an implicit intent.

Comment: You can use implicit intent to discover what URI's (is that even the right word) are available? Basically what i'm trying to figure out is what I can pass to the package that it'll know what to do with it. (How do I determine those things)

Answer (score 3):

The [Intents List: Google Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) has what I think you're asking for.

Comment: So using calculator as an example. I don't see it in that list, does that mean that publicly there isn't an intent available, and thus not promised for future releases? I am trying to figure out how to pass data to the calculator, but I want to understand how to figure it out, rather then having to ask you guys here.

Answer (score 1):

I got this solution from the DroidFu library

```
    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action, Uri uri, String mimeType) {
    final Intent intent = (uri != null) ? new Intent(action, uri) : new Intent(action);
    if (mimeType != null) {
        intent.setType(mimeType);
    }
    List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return !list.isEmpty();
}
```